# Trouble sizing Latex PDF page with Memoir

Tags: pdftex, memoir, geometry

I am trying to typeset a 5.25in x 8in book using LaTex and Memoir, and while I have managed to get a nice looking book, the problem is when the PDF is brought up the page dimensions are 5.50 x 8.50 instead of 5.25 x 8.  I looks fine otherwise.  Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[statementpaper,11pt,openany,twoside,extrafontsizes,final]{memoir}
\settrimmedsize{8in}{5.25in}{*}
\settrims{.25in}{.125in} % .25 and .125
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\linespread{1.05}
\headheight=17.5pt
\headsep=5pt
\addtolength{\uppermargin}{-1.29in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.29in}
\marginparwidth=25pt 
\foremargin=38pt
\spinemargin=46pt
\addtolength{\textwidth}{43pt}
\addtolength{\footskip}{8pt}
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\chapterstyle{dash}
\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.13in}
\widowpenalty=3500
\clubpenalty=300
\sloppy
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\tolerance=1500
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\newpage
\begin{center}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Soulmates}
```

I tried adding

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.25in,paperheight=8in,pass]{geometry}
```

While this did size the final PDF properly  to 5.25 x 8 the odd page text block was shoved towards the outside margin.  Not extreme but enough to throw off the look I am going for.  Doing research I found that Memoir and Geometry don't play well together.  But I thought with "pass" added it would only change the page size, which is obviously not the case.  I would leave it except that some printers will vary if the PDF size is not exact.  Some books might be to the left, right, or printed too close to the top edge of the book.  I assume I am missing something.

I also tried without the geometry package

```
\pdfpagewidth=5.25in
\pdfpageheight=8in
```

to no avail and I also tried this with geomerty

```
\oddsidemargin=38pt 
\evensidemargin=38pt
```

but that also did nothing (when trying to fix the oddpage text block from being too close to the edge margin with Geometry package being used).  I have looked over the Memoir docs several times and right now I am quite frustrated.  Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please make something that is compliable and **minimal**. Plus why are you using all those `\setlength`, use the proper interfaces and it will set the PDF sizes automatically

Comment: I didn't write the template, it was written by another author and seemed to work perfectly.  This is my first time with LaTeX and the produced PDF looked exactly like what I wanted and printed the same when sent to CreateSpace.  The problem was when I switched to Lightning Source, then sometimes the book printed with a narrow margin at the top.  Come to find out the text block etc was perfect but the PDF page size was slightly too large. Hence LS's printing will vary book to book (CS compensated automatically apparently).  So now I am trying to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

The following will give a PDF 8.00 inches high, 5.25 inches wide. Not sure what else you want to do as far as margins go, but it's a start. References include the [memoir manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf), chapter 2 "Laying out the page", with a summary of steps in section 2.6 "Putting it all together". The preview below is of a two-page view, but each page is sized correctly.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setstocksize{8in}{5.25in}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.75in}{0.5in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.75in}{*}
\setheadfoot{\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{\baselineskip}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Mike Renfro.  The pagenation is off of course since the margins are a bit different.  The key apparently is \setstocksize{8in}{5.25in}  I thought \settrimmedsize would do the same thing and cut down the page to the right size. but apparently not.  It is a starting point and I will keep working with it.  Hopefully I can wrangle it to create the same margins and page numbers as before.

Comment: Yep. There's a fair amount of redundancy in the preamble you have, too: setting `\pdfpagewidth`, for example. It may take several reads through the Memoir manual, but it's all in there. You'll likely end up with a much simpler preamble that does what you want.

Comment: Yes the manual you gave is much better one than the one I was looking at previously.  And I was just thinking that \pdfpagewidth is extra.

Comment: @DarthNewton: In memoir, stocksize is the whole PDF, and trimmedsize is the finished work. These are analogous to the printing process, where stock paper (what is fed into the machine) is often larger than the trimmed size (after cutting away excess). Margins are measured relative to the trimmed size, since anything outside the trim area is waste paper. Some publishers want the PDF with stock=trim, others want the stock at a particular size that might be larger than trim, with trim centered vertically and horizontally in stock. Your 5.25x8 is among the standard trimmed sizes.

Comment: @RobtA Sorry for the delay had no idea you responded.  Yes I know.  However in this case some publishers/printers will shift the text every time the document is printed if the stocksize and trimsize do not match.  For example create space will say there is a problem and they "auto fix" it, which looks fine.  And it will print that way every time.  By contrast Lightning Source won't tell you there is a problem and some print batches the interior text will be near the top edge.  And if you are using running heads, it is a problem.  In my experience it is best to have stock=trim even if not asked